# Using LOGIN_USER() in Flask gets tricky

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am pretty new at Flask, I've been trying to implement login_user and it's not working. I 've already read the documentation and I can´t make it work.
This is my model

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "User"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    username = db.Column (db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column (db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    city= db.Column(db.String)
    review = db.relationship('Review',backref='User',lazy=True)

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
```

and my login def

```
@app.route("/login", methods= ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email=form.email.data
        password_login= form.password.data
    #make sure user exists
        user= db.execute('''SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE email = :email''',{"email": email}).fetchone()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password,password_login):
                login_user(user, form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for("dashboard")) 
        return '<h1> Invalid user </h1>'    
    return(render_template("login.html", form=form))
```

I have the loader in app.py . I still can´t figure if I should place it in the model or not.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

And I got most of this error

`login_user(user, form.remember.data)
File "C:\Users\COMPAQ\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 166, in login_user
if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'is_active'`

My apologies if the mistake is obvious but I'm still strugling with the logic on the login system of Flask
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the wrong line, it was the query. Replaced it with :

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email=request.form.get('email')).first()
```

Found the answer here http://quabr.com/58256369/problem-with-logging-user-in-without-using-orm-could-not-locate-column-in-row

Hope it helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the methods in the class. Then you use a user loader function for flask login outside the model.

Then use `login_user()`

I also suggest you check out Miguel's Flask Mega Tutorial